# linq anon object utilizing parent object properties and child object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having difficulty constructing an anon object utilizing properties from both the parent and child related classes (this is probably not the correct terminology so please correct me if i'm wrong)

Given:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string SomePropertyINeedToUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create an anon object consisting of Foo.UserId and Foo.Bars.SomeProperty (one object for each list item Bar.SomeProperty and Foo.UserId combo)

This is what I have so far, but am uncertain on how to pull 1/many from the two objects - also see mocked up objects at

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FFO5x7

```
   // Here I can get Foo information, but unsure how to get bar
   var items =
      from f in this.Foos
      select new 
      {
         UserId = f.UserId
         SomeProperty = null// how to get Bar.SomeProperty?
      };

   // Here I can get Bar information, but unsure how to get Foo
   var items =
      from b in this.Foos.SelectMany(sm => sm.Bars)
      select new 
      {
         UserId = null // how to get Foo.UserId?
         SomeProperty = b.SomeProperty 
      };
```

Given the data from the fiddle what i'd like is anon objects as such:

```
{ 1, "test" },
{ 1, "Other Test" },
{ 2, "Blah Test" },
{ 2, "Blah Other test" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following

```
var items = from f in this.Foos
            from b in f.Bars
            select new
            {
                UserId = f.UserId,
                SomeProperty = b.SomeProperty
            };
```

Comment: Thanks! that's a lot easier than I thought :O

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.100).aspx) of `SelectMany`:

```
this.Foos.SelectMany(sm => sm.Bars, 
           (f,s) => new { UserId = f.Id, SomeProperty = s.SomeProperty });
```

Comment: Thanks!  That syntax is a bit tough to wrap my head around (but i often think lambda is) :(